# How to decode multipart/form data sent to web2py (python)?

Tags: python, web2py, forms, multipartform-data

I am trying to send an image via HTML form to a web2py web server for storing:

```
   <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://foo.bar.com/app/uploadimage" method="post">
        <input id="image-file" name="uploadfile" type="file" /><br>
        <input type="submit" /><br>
    </form>
```

The image sent to the server is encoded as `multipart/form-data`

In web2py (or I guess, python in general), how should I decode this data and save it as an image? Which tools are appropriate for this?

```
def uploadimage():    
    print request.vars.uploadfile
    # (... and now? ...)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

OK, turns out this is really simple, just do:

```
file = open('uploadimage.jpg', 'wb') 
file.write(request.vars.uploadfile.file.read()) 
file.close()
```